# Basic C++ Linked list nodes & Pointer Probs

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I've been having trouble trying to retrieve data from the first node in my linked list for quite some time now. Forgive me, but I am still new to C++ and especially pointers and linked lists.

Here is how I am reading the data from my text file (working fine so far)

```
void readFile(ifstream& budgetFile, budgetItem *newNode, int& counter, budgetItem *temp, budgetItem *header)
{
char pauseChar;

int ctype;
string cname;
double camount;
char cleared;

itemPtr listTop = NULL;

while (!budgetFile.eof())
{

    //newNode = new budgetItem;

    budgetFile >> ctype >> cname >> camount >> cleared;

    newNode->theType = ctype;
    cout << newNode->theType << endl;
    //cout << ctype << endl;
    newNode->name = cname;
    cout << newNode->name << endl;
    newNode->amount = camount;
    cout << newNode->amount << endl;
    if (cleared == 'Y') {
        newNode->cleared = true;
    }
    else{
        newNode->cleared = false;
    }

    newNode->next = listTop;
    listTop = newNode;

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        header = newNode;
    }

    counter++;
}

return;
}
```

And here is how I am trying to retrieve the data starting from the first node. It doesn't work at all. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
void showBudget (budgetItem *newNode, budgetItem *temp, budgetItem *header)
{
double incomeTotal;
double expenseTotal;
double differenceTotal;

//itemPtr *newlist;
//newNode = header;
itemPtr listTop;

budgetItem *here = listTop;

do {
    cout << "INCOME:" << endl;
    cout << "      Item              Amount       Cleared" << endl;
    cout << "      ----------------  -------      -------" << endl;
    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        cout << "List is empty." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (newNode->theType != 0)
        {
            cout << "       " << newNode->name << setw(23) << fixed << setprecision(2) << newNode->amount << "        ";
            if (newNode->cleared == true) {
                cout << "no" << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "yes" << endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    newNode = newNode->next;
} while (newNode != NULL);

cout << "End of List." << endl;

return;
}
```

Comment: You need to create a new node in every iteration of the loop, as you did in the out-commented statement.

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with this code. Principally, as @Cheersandhth.-Alf points out, you're not creating new nodes, you're overwriting a single node. More generally you're writing lots of code before testing any of it, and failing to decouple your functions. Start with a simpler Node class, test everything, then build up step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // ... 
    counter++;

    // create next node here:
    newNode = new budgetItem;
}
```

For each new element in the list we need to allocate new object in memory. You were using the same object again and again.